# How are constraints defined in schema? Is it by Store Procedure, User defined function or T-SQL or PL/SQL in the Database?

Tags: database, constraints, database-agnostic

How does SQL Server or Oracle or any database server applies constraints on the table>

I am aware of constraints, but how they are applied on the table or a column? I tried to find how SQL Server understands a requirement for a constraint and maintain the integrity.

Is there a Store Procedure or User defined function for applying a constraint?  How does database server understand this scenario, when user is requested for mount a constraint on a table?

Comment: is it a really tough question that no one able to answer this.or a idiotic one

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand.  Are you asking how a database administrator *creates* a constraint on a column, or how the database engine *enforces* the constraint when rows are inserted or updated?

Comment: How database enforces the Consraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [Microsoft's documentation page on constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189862.aspx)? There are many types of constraints so the [DML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177591%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) syntax will differ for each. To your direct question no, they are not applied by using stored procs or UDF's, it's just TSQL syntax.  You can also right-click on a table in [SSMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) and go into the designer. All constraint types can be managed their instead of raw TSQL.